# Change position of legend in plot of pec object

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot the prediction error curve from pec package but I can't change the legend position and size. There's an example from pec package:

```
library(rms)
library(pec)
data(pbc)
pbc <- pbc[sample(1:NROW(pbc),size=100),]
f1 <- psm(Surv(time,status!=0)~edema+log(bili)+age+sex+albumin,data=pbc)
f2 <- coxph(Surv(time,status!=0)~edema+log(bili)+age+sex+albumin,data=pbc,x=TRUE,y=TRUE)
f3 <- cph(Surv(time,status!=0)~edema+log(bili)+age+sex+albumin,data=pbc,surv=TRUE)
brier <- pec(list("Weibull"=f1,"CoxPH"=f2,"CPH"=f3),data=pbc,formula=Surv(time,status!=0)~1)
print(brier)
plot(brier)
```

But shows a big the legend in the middle of plot.

[image]

I also tried:

```
plot(brier, legend = "topright")
class(brier)
```

But don't show legend.

[image]

How can I change the position of legend? And also ¿is it posible to plot this graph using ggplot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got what you want using `ggplot2`. The idea is to pick elements from your `brier` object that contains data for the plot, make a dataframe with it and plot it.

```
library(ggplot2)
# packages for the pipe and pivot_wider, you can do it with base functions, I just prefer these
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- do.call(cbind, brier[["AppErr"]]) # contains y values for each model
df <- cbind(brier[["time"]], df) # values of the x axis
colnames(df)[1] <- "time"             
df <- as.data.frame(df) %>% pivot_longer(cols = 2:last_col(), names_to = "models", values_to = "values") # pivot table to long format makes it easier to use ggplot

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = time, y = values, color = models)) +
  geom_line() # I suppose you know how to custom axis names etc.
```

Output:

[image]